# How to syntax dynamic insert in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, insert, user-input, plpgsql

I was wondering if there is a way to syntax an `INSERT` using `EXECUTE` in `plpgsql`.

Suppose I want to have a dynamic insert with mutliple `IF`s. I try to create something like the following

```
CREATE  FUNCTION __a_inj(creator text) RETURNS integer   
  AS $query$
  DECLARE ii ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE'
    INSERT INTO deleteme(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id'
    USING creator;
    return ii;

END;
$query$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call it with `select __a_inj('drop table deleteme;--');` and get

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "drop table deleteme;--"
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function __a_inj(text) while casting return value
>   to function's return type SQL state: 22P02

If I replace the `INSERT` line with `INSERT INTO deleteme(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id into ii'` I get

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "into" LINE 2: ...  INSERT INTO
>   deleteme(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id into ii

If the function is

```
CREATE  FUNCTION __a_inj(creator text) RETURNS integer   
  AS $query$
  DECLARE ii ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
    RETURN EXECUTE'
    INSERT INTO deleteme(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id into ii'
    USING creator;
    --return ii;

END;
$query$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING" LINE 8:     USING creator;

How can I have a dynamic `INSERT` with `EXECUTE`

**OR**

I guess there is no need to syntax one. Just use ifs to create the INTO and values part and then use a simple `INSERT` that is also strong against SQL injection attacks ?

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE`), but the second one has a syntax error (there is no `INTO` clause in SQL). You get the error in the first statement because the string you insert cannot be converted to an integer.

You are safe from SQL injection if you use the `USING` clause, because that uses a statement with parameters. SQL injection can only happen if you concatenate a user input string with an SQL statement.

Comment: About the first. But I am using a text to do an insert and then I grab the integer id that the insert successfully returned and try to return it. I dont get what is wrong. I am trying something like the second parameter, I removed the `DECLARE ii` part and I get an error about the `USING` part : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"`. Anyway I keep on looking at it

Comment: `'drop table deleteme;--'` is not a valid integer. This has nothing to do with `RETURNING`. In the second statement, it is not the `DECLARE` that is wrong, it is the `INTO ii`.